# How to select the date from the calender box as same from the spreadsheet

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Thanks in advance for my reply.
I want to select the calendar from the calendar box.
I tried to send the code using selenium with python.
It is not able to select the correct date.
It is getting displayed as 21 -- ju--l- 22 instead of 21-JUL-2023
Below i have given the code and screenshot.
Please help me to select the correct calendar.
code:_

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='indentFromDateTxt']").send_keys("01-Jul-2023")
```

I did inspect the code to get the xpath and it is showing below

```
<input type="text" id="indentFromDateTxt" name="indentFromDateTxt" style="width: 230px;" onfocus="" class="hasDatepick calendar" maxlength="11">
```

Please help me to code. thanks
[image]

Comment: Can you try `calendar.send_keys("07/01/2023")` or `01/07/2023` based on date format?

Comment: i am trying this one also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you shouldn't define delimiter - it is visible for user, but not the part of entered value.

Sending value like `01Jul2023` works for me for inputs on your site.

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='indentFromDateTxt']").send_keys("01Jul2023")
```

Answer (score 0):

Below the code is working for me. Thank you everyone for the help

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='indentFromDateTxt']").send_keys("01Jul2023")
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='indentToDateTxt']").send_keys("31Jul2023")
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='stampIssuedDateTxt']").send_keys("19Oct2023")
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
```